# Oracle SQL Developer. Не полностью отображается поле типа CLOB

Tags: oracle

В Oracle SQL Developer 4.2.0.16 View Value выводит только часть текста поля типа CLOB.[image: SQLdev]

Comment: Разобрался. Версия 4.2.0 это версия с ранним доступом. Поставил стабильную версию SQL Developer 4.1.5 и всё заработало.